# dropdown name values with space to controller in jquery ajax json in codeigniter

Tags: ajax, codeigniter, datatables

I try to send the product name to controller to get the product details from DB in via of ajax in code igniter but script is broken in space between the name fields...i want to show the db values in datatable

**my view**

```
  <select  onChange = "getProductTable()" name="product_id" id="product_id" class="form-control select2">
                                        <option value="">Select Product</option>
                                        <?php foreach ($product as $row) : ?>
                                        <option **value="<?php echo $row->name ?>"**>
                                            <?php echo $row->name ?></option>
                                        <?php endforeach; ?>
    
                                    </select>
```

**script**

```
 function getProductTable(){
    var productID1= $('#product_id').val(); 
    
    var product_id = $("#product_id option:selected").val(); 
    console.log("product_id Name "+productID1) ;
     console.log("product_id1 Name "+product_id ) ;
     var list = 'admin/product/productListTable2/'+product_id1;
      if (list != "") {
                loadTable(list,product_id1); /* fetching the DataTable to view
            }
    }
```

ajax datatable console

product_id Name HEX BOLT
product_id1 Name HEX BOLT
productList2:653 D is [object Object]
productList2:655 URL is http://localhost/eOffice/admin/product/productListTable2/**HEX BOLT**

script is broken of space between HEX and BOLT and send the data as HEX so that i cannot get the db values
help me how to send the full name with space to controller to get the db values

Comment: help me how to send the selected name from dropdown to controller to get the db values by name "HEX BOLT"

Comment: my script is broken in space btween HEX and BOLT so that i cannot get the db values